# Server side application

Tags: java, php, python, django, server-side

for my new project I need to write server-side application that will serve some of simple requests. I have no experience of writing server-side application, so I need some advice.
The problem is that I don't know how to start; I've spent couple of hours searching google for some guidelines, but I got nowhere.
I need to write application that will ran on the server (I've installed Ubuntu server in VirtualBox and used briged connection, so I can access it from my network) and will serve some requests:

- connnect to server
- authorize user (check user and his pass in db)
- store some data in db on connection (for example IP address)

I am not sure which language would be best to use and what do I need to know to implement that app. This is my private project, which I came up with to learn something new; until now I have always written apps that ran locally (usually in Java/C/Python).

I've seen some tutorials on PHP and Django, but I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for all help :)

Comment: Anything can work.  Write the one you know best or want to learn the most.  There is no "right" direction.

Comment: Which communcation protocols should I look at ? I am not sure how to implement communication between application that is running on the server and application that is requesting a service.

Comment: Just one: HTTP.  Simple and open won - the whole world uses web services.  Why would you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to you meteorjs look at www.meteor.com  the reason why im prefering this to you is that i was in the same position as you one month ago and i,m amaized with meteorjs. Also have a look at derbyjs. This frameworks are built on top of node.js it allows you to write only javascript end to end.

Look at install.meteor.com you will find a quick install bash file.

At the end you can do this with any of the languages you mentioned. Write with what you like the most.

Comment: I was already looking at Node.JS but if I understand correctly it is a front-end language. Thanks anyway, I will have a look.

Comment: Javascript was used as a front end until nodejs was invented. And now it is used also for server side. https://www.meteor.com look at the video in the first page